# How can i follow the uninstall of Flutter Desktop application?

Tags: flutter

I have a desktop app built for Windows, macOS, and Linux using Flutter. It stores user files locally using Hive as an offline-only application. I show this info on splash screen.

During uninstallation, I want to prompt the user with an option to export their files to their Documents folder.

This would prevent unaware users from losing their data when the app's local files are deleted. Is this achievable with Flutter?